# Why does tikz's positioning library add whitespace on the left side of my diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, white-space

Why does tikz's `positioning` library add whitespace on the left side of my diagram?

With `positioning`:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without positioning:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{white}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There still seems to be a big of extra whitespace on the left, but not much.

Comment: Always load libraries in the preamble. They are similar to packages.

Answer (score 2):

Grrrrr, it's the stuff between `\begin{document}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}` that's the culprit.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagecolor{white}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Partially it's the unescaped line endings in your original example which all act like one space (the rest of the spaces comes from tikz itself)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat